# How to escape curly braces in hibernate validator messages (test case provided)

Tags: escaping, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to put something like {this} as a message value for hibernate validator validation message.

so i escaped the value of this given message in properties file :\{this\}

however Hibrnate Validator tries to check if there is a message for given key.
I think this is a bug but maybe I am doing something wrong? (tested with hibernate-validator 4.3.1 and 5.0.1 - same result - stack overflow

test case:

(for simplification it does not have properties file, i just return value from java class. In reality handleGetObject would read the value from my custom-provided properties):

```
import org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator;
import org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl;
import org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator;
import org.hibernate.validator.spi.resourceloading.ResourceBundleLocator;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.validation.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Set;


public class HibValTest {

@Test
public void shouldNotSubstituteEscaped() throws Exception {

    MessageInterpolator interpolator = new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator( new ResourceBundleLocator() {

        @Override
        public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
            return new ResourceBundle() {

                @Override
                protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
                    return "\\{escapedKey\\}";
                }

                @Override
                public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
    }, false);

    HibernateValidatorConfiguration config = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class ).configure();
    config = config.messageInterpolator(interpolator).constraintValidatorFactory(new ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl());

    ValidatorFactory factory = config.buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<A>> validate = validator.validate(new A());
}

private class A {
    @Max(value=1, message = "{key}")
    private int a=2;
}
}
```

result:

```
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.resolveParameter(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:244)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateBundleMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:211)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.resolveParameter(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:244)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateBundleMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:211)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.resolveParameter(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:244)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateBundleMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:211)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.resolveParameter(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:244)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateBundleMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:211)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug indeed. Could you create a ticket in our [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV), please?

For the time being, you could work around this by not providing a value for the escaped key (if that's possible in your case), e.g. like so:

```
protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
    return key.equals("key") ? "\\{escapedKey\\}" : null;
}
```

Comment: as for your workaround proposal - it is currently not convenient for us as we return '???key???' for a missing key to see that something is missing in properties.